# Can not determine file format for @path to the obj file@ USDZ windows

Tags: windows, .obj, usdz

i am trying to convert my usda to usdz using the usdzip command line tool provided by [pixar](https://graphics.pixar.com/usd/docs/USD-Toolset.html). i have managed to successfully build the package using their official [build-method](https://github.com/PixarAnimationStudios/USD). however when i try to view the usda or usdz using the usdzview command line tool i get this error

Cannot determine file format for @path-to-.obj-file@

Couldn't find any helpful documentation regarding the issue.

If anyone has face similar issue what am i doing wrong.

Btw i am using this [guide](https://blendersushi.blogspot.com/2018/07/pipeline-understanding-usdz-format-for.html) to construct my usda and referencing my obj file as

```
def "Mesh_0" (
    add references = @path-to-obj@</Suzanne>
)
```